# How to fix "flutter: DatabaseException(open_failed...)"?

Tags: ios, database, flutter, sqflite

I'm trying to run my flutter app on my iPhone 7 but I'm receiving an error message. Running the app on my Android phone as well as on the iPhone XR simulator works fine.
I also tried to test the app on my iPad and I got the exact same error message as shown below. Replacing the ios folder with a fresh copy did not solve the issue.

I've tried to run the latest sqflite version and flutter doctor shows no issues.

```
Future<Database> initDatabase() async {
    //Get the dir
    Directory directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String path = directory.path + 'posts.db';

    //Open or Create the database using given path
    var postsDataBase = openDatabase(path, version: 1, onCreate: _createDb);
    return postsDataBase;
  }

[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: DatabaseException(open_failed /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/04C0A23F-6C36-42C2-9CE5-C7C5370F59FA/Documentsposts.db)
#0      wrapDatabaseException 
package:sqflite/src/exception_impl.dart:11
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      SqfliteDatabaseFactoryImpl.wrapDatabaseException 
package:sqflite/src/factory_impl.dart:29
#2      SqfliteDatabaseMixin.safeInvokeMethod 
package:sqflite/src/database_mixin.dart:184
#3      SqfliteDatabaseMixin.openDatabase 
package:sqflite/src/database_mixin.dart:519
<asynchronous suspension>
#4      SqfliteDatabaseMixin.doOpen 
package:sqflite/src/database_mixin.dart:612
<asynchronous suspension>
#5      SqfliteDatabaseOpenHelper.openDatabase 
package:sqflite/src/database.dart:32
<asynchronous suspension>
#6      SqfliteDatabaseFactoryMixin.openDatabase.<anonymous closure> 
package:sqflite/src/factory_mixin.dart:100
<asynchronous suspension>
#7      ReentrantLock.synchronized.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> 
package:synchronized/src/reentrant_lock.dart:33
#8      _rootRun  (dart:async/zone.dart:1124:13)
```

Comment: what is the complete stacktrace and your code that makes your problems?

Comment: Do you mean the excerpts from the debug console?

Comment: yes, the debug console, post top 5-8 frames

Comment: and what is your code where you are using `openDatabase`?

Comment: I do remember there was a popup when I launched XCode to upgrade to Swift 5 I guess. Could this be an issue?

Answer (score 2):

Using db helper like this fixed my issue:

```
  Future<String> checkPath(String dbName) async {
    var databasePath = await getDatabasesPath();
    String path = join(databasePath, dbName);
    if (await Directory(dirname(path)).exists()) {
    } else {
      try {
        await Directory(dirname(path)).create(recursive: true);
      } catch (e) {
        print(e);
      }
    }
    return path;
  }

  initDB() async {
    String path = await checkPath(dbName);

    return await openDatabase(
      (path),
      onCreate: (db, version) {
    ...
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the parent directory exists or not and try using the latest sqlite version.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
String path = directory.path + '/' + 'posts.db';
```

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the logs, the path you build ends with `/Documentsposts.db`  where I think you likely want `/Documents/posts.db`

Don't use the plus sign to build a path but use `join` from the package `path`.

i.e. instead of:

```dart
String path = directory.path + 'posts.db';
```

do

```dart
var path = join(directory.path, 'posts.db');
```

On iOS you should also make sure the parent directory exists first.